# jQuery Child Selector by class

Tags: jquery, parent-child, insertafter

I have the following html structure, and would like to insert a `div` using jQuery in the indicted place.

```
<div class="item" data-url-id="intro">
    <div class="title-wrapper">      
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- want to insert the element here -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this code:

```
$( "div[class='item'][data-url-id='intro'] > div[class='title-wrapper']" ).after( "<div class='...'>...</div>");
```

Essentially, the 'inside' `div`'s do not have ids, and must thusly be identified by class.

I thought the above meant *"insert an element after a `div` of class 'title-wrapper' that is a child of  a `div` with class 'item' AND an attribute of 'data-url-id' who's value is 'intro'"*.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Zephyr

Comment: Working fine!! http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/d5L8x0q5/ What is an issue?

Comment: Oh, lord.  I've got to go back to the website now for the problem - thanks for verifying my logic/code.  The issue is that code doesn't generate the intended `div`, but other elements are being created on the page.  I thought the expression was wrong, but it's working fine per your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery selectors can be simplified a little bit:

`$('.item[data-url-id=intro] > .title-wrapper').after('<div>Inserted Element</div>');`

Here's a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ys5j0ac/

Comment: I think this did the trick!  Maybe the KISS principle is best.

Answer (score 1):

the use of after function is correct but you do not need to specify so many selectors. Also you can use the dot '.' operator as class selector. for your case it can be:

```
$(".title-wrapper").after( "<div class='...'>...</div>");
```

however if you expect that another div with class **title-wrapper** where do not want to have the div inserted you can write it as.

```
$(".item > .title-wrapper").after( "<div class='...'>...</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `title-wrapper` is the only div with this class, you could try code like:

```
$( ".title-wrapper" ).after( "<div>new div</div>" );
```

or you may try this:

```
$( "div[class='item'][data-url-id='intro'] > div[class='title-wrapper']" ).after( "<div>new div</div>");
```